# Why do my deleted branches on Github keep rcoming back?

Tags: git, github

Deleting stale branches on Github seems simple, as does renaming branches. When I view my branches I have buttons for both. After I delete or rename a branch it deletes or renames appropriately after my action.

My deleted branches keep coming back, however, and I also see both the old and the renamed branches. What could I be doing wrong to make this happen?

Comment: Since Git is a *distributed* version control system, branches that are deleted from github can still exist in clones of the repository.  Depending on the operators' workflows, they could be pushing those branches back up to git.

Comment: @erik258 Thanks for your help. Is all they need to do is pull first before pushing? Or do they need to do more than that?

Comment: see if they're doing something like `git push --all origin` which would push all branches .  I would never run that command personally.

Comment: I'll send out an e-mail asking our developers if someone is pushing -all like this. Honestly, there's only 3 of us and I'm pretty sure I know the guy doing it.